# Neo4J REST Unique Nodes

Tags: rest, neo4j

My question is two parts:

First, when trying to create a unique node using the REST Interface like below...

```
http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/people?uniqueness=create_or_fail
```

What is the meaning of the "person" portion of the URL.  I'm under the impression that it is a label but I'm not sure.

Second, if it is indeed a label, when I execute the following REST call...

```
http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/Test?uniqueness=create_or_fail
```

with this payload...

```
{
    key: "name",
    value: "test",
    properties: 
    {
       "lastName": "test",
       "name": "test",
       "type": "test",
       "firstName": "test"
    }
}
```

A node is created but does not have an associated label.  It creates a label-less node that does still enforce uniqueness.  How do I create a unique node using the REST API with a label?

I'm using neo4j 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are correct. When you send in JSON, it will create the node, or fail if it already exists using the index label 'people'
2. When sending, you need to have in your object a "key" and "value" which denotes how to do the index matching.

How are you determining that the node has no label? In the REST documentation, I can see that the labels is a different URL call for a node, have you checked there?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I goofed on my payload (it's updated now).  It does include the key and value.  I determined that it was not including the label because if I run "match n where n.name='test' return n", the nodes show up.  If I run "match n:Test where n.name='test' return n;" it does not.

Comment: Hm. I've not played around with labels yet. You're saying in your second query that the entire node doesn't show up, or just the label?

Comment: After running "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/Test?uniqueness=create_or_fail" with my payload, a node is created.  If I run the same REST call again, it fails (as expected, because a node with the name "test" already exists).  If I run a query in the shell to look at all the nodes that exist, there will be one record (the node I just created).  If I look at all nodes with the "Test" label, I am returned no records.  My assumption is that the node is being created without a label.

Comment: Perhaps. As said, I'm not very familiar, but it seems like that is what it's doing. When you get all nodes back, you don't see a label on the node, do you?

Comment: I'm rather new to neo4j as well.  I'm actually not sure how to write a query to explicitly display nodes with their associated labels.  I'm thoroughly confused here...

Comment: You can do `START nodes=node(*) RETURN n, labels(n)`

Comment: Ahh thanks!  Yes, so there are definitely no labels attached to the node.  I'm wondering if "person" in the first REST call is the name of the index that is being searched as opposed to the name of the label.  I really appreciate your help and thoughts on this.